# How to get the new value and cancel the event in an text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html-input

I have a input (`type=text`) and I want to check whether the value is valid after it is changed. Currently I do it like this:

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateInput(event)"></input>
```

```js
function validateInput(event) {
    var ascii = event.keyCode;
    if(ascii == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I don't only need to check what the entered character is, but also where in the string it is added. Therefore I'd like to know the new value of the input, but `onkeypress` event does not seem to have an attribute like this. `onchange` event would allow me to get the new value and compare it to the old value, but then I would not be able to cancel the event by returning `false` anymore.

Is there a way to combine both cancelling the event and knowing the new value (or the position at which the new character is added in the current string)?

Comment: Why do you need to `return false`, How does it prevent you from using `onchange`

Comment: Well, returning `false` is cancelling the `onkeypress` event, isn't it? With the `onchange` event returning `false` does not cancel the event, the new character is added anyway.

Comment: Okay If you use keypress, you use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`

Comment: You can Refer to @Guerric's Answer. It is the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You can use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to block the default behaviour associated with the event.

```js
function validateInput(event) {
    let ascii = event.keyCode;
    if(ascii == 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateInput(event)"></input>
```

With this soultion, you have to regard is that `Event.preventDefault()` blocks the default behaviour the throwing instance might have. This can become an issue when you rely on this default behaviour. But in this case you deliberately block the element's default behaviour (which is adding a character to it's content).

## Option 2

You can simply remember the text before the change and restore it afterwards if the change was invalid.

```js
var previousValue = "";
var iskeyDown = false;

function savePrevious(event)
{
  if(iskeyDown == false) // If the button wasn't released since the last evoke of this event...
  {
    // Do nothing
    return;
  }
  // Save the value before the change
  previousValue = document.getElementById("MyInput").value
  
  //Remember the key is pressed
  iskeyDown = true;
}

function validateInput(event)
{
  let myInputElement = document.getElementById("MyInput")
  console.log(myInputElement.value)
  if(true) // If new value is invalid...
  {
    //Roll back to before the change
    myInputElement.value = previousValue
  }
  // Remember that the key has been released
  iskeyDown = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="MyInput" type="text" onkeydown="savePrevious(event)" onkeyup="validateInput(event)"></input>
```

Not that `keydown` and `keypress` are performed before the change is made to the text box' `value` member and `keyup` afterwards.

It should also be noted that some browsers might send these events multiple times, so you need a mechanism (here realized with `var iskeyDown`) to avoid reacting to the same event multiple times. Otherwise you might get strange results.

Comment: Well, the question is how to "react", because cancelling the event by returning `false`, as I did it before, is not working with `keyup` event, is it?

Comment: Ah, it seems i misunderstood the question then. I thought you were looking for a way to check for the whole text at once. I'll adapt **Option 2** to let you revert invalid changes.

Comment: Okay, **Option 2** reverts invalid changes now.

Comment: Thank you, something like this would work. However with this approach one doen't cancel the event, but instead just rolls back to the previous value. The problem with that is, that one will see the new value for like a second, before it changes back to the old one. Any idea how to fix that issue?

Comment: Well, option 1 prevents this. For option 2, you also could first write the new value into a buffer and update it to the field on keyup. But then the user would see the change only after releasing the key again what also doesn't sound too intuitive.

Comment: Yeah my problem with option one was that I didnt know where in the previous string the new character was added. But I found a way using `event.target.selectionStart` (cursor position), now it's working fine. I'll still accept this answer, even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the event you are looking for is input, you can read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Comment: How would that help with knowing the new value of the input field?

Comment: `e.target.value`?